# Access/Output Values in Flattened Hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

In my controller I have:

```
@invoices = current_user.account.clients.map(&:invoices).flatten
```

and in my index.html.erb I want to display the values, currently I have the following:

```
<% @invoices.each do |invoice| %>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><%= invoice.client.name %></td>
        <td><%= invoice.jobs.inspect %></td> #HERE IS WHERE I WANT START_DATE, etc
        <td><%= invoice.created_at %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "PDF", invoice_path(invoice, :format => :pdf)%></td>
        <td><%= link_to invoice, :method => :delete, :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete this invoice' do %> <i class="icon-trash"></i><% end %>
    </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

invoice.jobs.inspect returns the following:

```
[#<Job id: 15, start_date: "2012-03-24", due_date: "2012-03-31", notes: "grthryrth", audio_file_url: "1.txt", transcribed_file_url: "300.txt", status: "invoiced", account_id: 1, user_id: 1, client_id: 2, created_at: "2012-03-29 18:03:14", updated_at: "2012-03-29 18:40:49", invoice_id: 6>, #<Job id: 16, start_date: "2012-03-24", due_date: "2012-03-21", notes: "uopuiouioiio", audio_file_url: "Data Flow Analysis and Integration v1.1.docx", transcribed_file_url: "ECA-Sponsor Monthly Agenda 20120105.doc", status: "invoiced", account_id: 1, user_id: 4, client_id: 2, created_at: "2012-03-29 18:05:24", updated_at: "2012-03-29 18:40:49", invoice_id: 6>]
```

How do I access each value individually, for example, invoice.jobs.start_date?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get Invoices then going through the User model seems backwards to me. Consider something like this instead:

```
@invoices = Invoice.joins( :client => { :accounts => :user } ).
                    include( :client, :jobs ).
                    where( "accounts.user_id" => current_user.id ).
                    all
```

Either way, though, if `invoice.jobs` is an array (as evidenced by its being plural and the square brackets in its `inspect` output) then you first need to access an element of the array using e.g. `[0]` or `first`:

```
invoice.jobs.first.start_date
# => "2012-03-24"
```

Comment: Thanks.  So if I have more than 1 job in an invoice, how would I display that?  By using invoice.jobs[0].start_date obviously only returns the value of the first jobs item, not subsequent ones.

Comment: In that case you would loop through the collection e.g. `invoice.jobs.each do |job| ...` or [pass it to a partial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections). The latter is more "Railsy," probably.

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one way to go : you can override `inspect` in your jobs model, create another method (something like `pretty_display`, whatever) if you don't want to mess up `inspect`, or use a view helper (something like `job_pretty_display(job)`). I'd go with the 3rd option.